# What are the advantages of using iText over JasperReports in generating PDFS?

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

Currently i am using jasper report for generating pdfs in my application.As there is need for generating more pdfs, i found a pdf library iText.
As i am new to iText, Can anybody suggest what are the advantages to use iText over JasperReport ?

Comment: Your question indicates a misconception here: JasperReports itself uses (an older version of) iText to create PDFs, too. Thus, its ***not* either JasperReports or iText** but instead **iText either via JasperReports or directly**.

Comment: Jasper report provides a tool (iReport) to create report template. It may seems trivial but it will save your time(if you have lots of reports to produce). IText is PDF rendering library and as @mkl suggested Jasperreport uses itext internally to generate PDF. With Jasper you can have multiple types of output (doc, csv, html etc)